# finding prime numbers greater than 10^12

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, primes

What is the sum of all prime numbers between 1,000,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,100,000?
this works out but is very slow.I need to optimize it.I am new to python.
**3614000181007876** is the right answer

```
    A=10 ** 6
N=A+1
B=10 ** 5
prime=[]
sum=0
for i in range(0,N):
    prime.append(0)
for i in range(2,N):
    if(prime[i]==1):
        continue
    for j in range(i*i,N,i):
        prime[j]=1
for i in range((A ** 2)+1,(A ** 2)+B,2):
    for j in range(2,A):
        c=0
        if(prime[j]==1):
            continue
        if(i%j==0):
            c=c+1
            if(c>0):
                break
    if(c==0):
        #print(i)
        sum=sum+i


print(sum)
```

Comment: Possible duplicates...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703699/program-to-find-all-primes-in-a-very-large-given-range-of-integers

Comment: google "sieve of eratosthenes"

Comment: seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python

Comment: The sum of all primes between 1,000,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,100,000 is 5042000251194180; using `primes` from my `bsdgames` Debian package as `primes 1000000000000 1000000100000|awk '{s += $1}END{print s}'` -computed in less than a hundredth of second

Comment: I get the same result.  bsdgames is available in Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : 3614000181007876 is the right answer

Comment: Could you explain in the question how you know the correct answer?

Comment: @Paul Strangly enough, I get the same result as OP: 3614000181007876

Comment: I tried finding the list of primes with "primes" from bsdgames and doing the sum in python and obtained 5041000251194141.  This is different from what awk found, so maybe there is an issue. I note that bsdgames "primes" finds 5042 such primes.  The first one being 1000000000039 and the last one being 1000000099979.  I haven't checked if these are actually primes, just noting the nature of the output from this method.

Comment: @Paul I fear that 1000000099979 = 877853 * 1139143 and hence composite. Looks like a shitty primes package to me.

Comment: Yup, I see that too. I suppose primes is in "bsdgames" for a reason...  I was curious.

Comment: I can confirm there are 3614 such primes and their sum is 3614000181007876. Takes 0.1 sec to calculate on a normal today's box (mine is slower, but I know the coefficient:)). The code is at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Above_Limit_-_Offset_Sieve. It's the "offset" sieve of Eratosthenes. Imperative  pseudocode is [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19641049/849891). C code is [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557173/849891).

Comment: there are 78498 primes below 1000000.05. that's all that we need, to sieve the interval from 10^12 to 10^12+10^5.

Comment: primes is not valid above 2**32 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bsdgames/+bug/725367

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the most efficient way, but gets the right result (hopefully 3614000181007876) in 2 seconds on my box:

```
def isPrime(n):
    d = n - 1
    s = 0
    while not d & 1:
        s += 1
        d >>= 1
    for a in (2, 13, 23, 1662803):
        if pow(a, d, n) != 1 and all(pow(a, (1 << r) * d, n) != n - 1 for r in range(0, s)):
            return False
    return True

print(sum(x for x in range(1000000000001, 1000000100000, 2) if isPrime(x)))
```

Comment: it's fast....can u explain me ur way

Comment: It is just a deterministic Miller-Rabin-Test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test